# How to use specific strings with "if"

Tags: python-2.7

So I'm trying to do something with my code but can't figure out how to do it, because when I try doing (example)

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
if name = "Jack":
print "Your name is jack!"
```

It just gives me errors (the errors are the `=` at line 2 which I tried fixing and then it gave me the end quote as an error). Please help I can't figure out how to do it.

Even after fixing the mistakes I still have another mistake, I have no idea how I'm getting all these mistakes.
Here is my code : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUB7U.jpg

Comment: We really need more to go on than this. I am not even sure what your issue is exactly. Clarify your issue if you want help. I assume you are testing a command line prompt for the user name? If so, then why are you hardcoding the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your code as follows:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
if name == "Jack":
    print "Your name is jack!"
```

You are using single `=` operator to check the equality which is wrong and your code is also missing indentation.
Here is the working code https://ideone.com/qbUo3Z

Comment: Thank you very much. Also I didn't realize the indentation thing since like i have to type ctrl + k then do the indentation and i get confused.

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help.